# How can i make SQL requests/commands for these tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Was looking for the SQL lines to join two tables, but foind it on

Comment: Do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The number of orders made by each customer.

```
SELECT C.NAME, COUNT(O.id)
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.customer_id = C.ID
GROUP BY C.NAME
```

b) The list of all customers who have three or more orders.

```
SELECT C.NAME, COUNT(O.id)
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.customer_id = C.ID
GROUP BY C.NAME
HAVING COUNT(O.id) > 3
```

c) The list of all customers who have ordered the item named “test item”.

```
SELECT C.NAME, COUNT(O.id)
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.customer_id = C.ID
WHERE O.item_name = 'test item'
GROUP BY C.NAME
```

d) The list of all customers who have NOT ordered the item named “test item”.

```
SELECT C.NAME, COUNT(O.id)
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.customer_id = C.ID
WHERE O.item_name <> 'test item'
GROUP BY C.NAME
```